# GUI and Data loading parallel

Tags: c#, wpf, database, user-interface, parallel-processing

first of all, I've been reading a lot about this issue, but it's not clear in my mind.

I'm developing a WPF app that implies loading large sets of information from databases, local/remote files, webservices, and so on. Let's say, this data is loaded into datagrids and this kind of controls.

My app is working fine, but the data loading process generates bad user experiences. I'm going to focus in the main window, for example, which requests a lot of data, so it takes 2-3 seconds to be loaded and displayed in the grids.

What I really want to see in my app when I first execute it, is the GUI loaded inmediately, and then let the data loading work, displaying a spinner, waiting object, or whatever over the grids until these processes are (asynchronously?) loaded.

In this case (in my tests), no matter where the order to load the data (in the code, I mean) is made: inside the constructor, at the end of the several events (initialized, load, etc), in an Init method just before the ShowDialog instruction... the GUI window does not appear until my grids have the stuff loaded.

I guess that I should deal with threads, having one for GUI and another asynchronous for loading the data, but I've made some tests with Dispatcher, Delegates and so on and nothing successful.

To sum up, the goal is to load the GUI as fast as possible, and then to load the data and refresh the GUI.

Now I'm a little confused, I read issues about threads, dispatchers, etc, but I don't know if they are appliable to my needs. I hope you can tell me the way to follow.

Regards,
Borja.

Comment: I'm too lazy to read all you've written here. post some relevant code instead

Comment: BackgroundGround worker and priority binding.  And clean up the question.

Comment: Main solution is to avoid big datasets (after all, it's a GUI, with the U for User). Second option: start with a minimally filled VM and update the Lists (observables) from a thread.

Comment: have you enabled `Visualization` on your `DataGrids`

Answer (score 0):

It is technical thing, but usually you CHUNK the data into smaller items, using ObservableCollection. You add items on chunks of 20 and let the UI also show spinner, while remaining responsive. Keep the chunk load at 50ms, also you will never directly load data on UI thread, but on secondary thread(Background worker).

Answer (score 0):

If big datasets and loading all data into memory is absolutely required, then consider this:

When you make a synchronous call to a web service, you're not actually doing any processing, but you're locking execution until the result is returned.  If you use an asynchronous call you'll actually send the request, then your program will continue to execute until the web service returns a result.

If asynchronous calls won't work, just use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to do all of your data work on a different thread.

Both of these should result in freeing up the main thread and allowing the form to be rendered.

Comment: BackgroundWorker is working perfectly. For that purpuse, I', using two events of the BW: DoWork (to do my stuff), and RunWorkerCompleted (to update GUI). But taking into account (I don't know if my approach is correct) that GUI must be updated from the same thread that created the GUI stuff, so that this task must be done by the dispatcher this way:

**this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                // GUI updates
            }));**

Comment: Do you actually need to update the UI with data during DoWork? If you want to use a spinner like you question proposes I'm not sure why you would need this.Dispatcher.Invoke(), it's just an animation that continues until RunWorkerComplete.  If you want to pass a percent completion, you can use the BackgroundWorker's ReportProgress method.